# The relation between the (algebraic) dimensions of a normed linear space and its dual.

Tags: functional-analysis

What is the relation between the (algebraic) dimensions of a normed linear space and its dual, for example can we say $\dim X \leq \dim X^*$, for a normed linear space $X$?